# Pure CSS Responsive Vertical Ribbon

Tags: html, css, ribbon

I am trying to create a CSS responsive ribbon "end" for a RSS graphic. This will eventually become a Wordpress sidebar RSS widget.

I have it working on the desktop version just fine, although, when scaled down the ribbon portion of the widget does not scale along with everything else. I am wondering if I am attempting the impossible or approaching it the wrong way? I have created a version of this on [Codepen [here.]](http://codepen.io/jrock526/pen/LxitH)

Any help that anyone can lend in this challenge will be most helpful.

Comment: so the ribbon 'end', is it supposed to be above the events section? or below it? and is the arrow pointing in a V or a ^

Comment: The ribbon end would be above the list section in a V format. I do apologize and maybe I should make note that the ribbon is in place on the Codepen example, but does not present itself until the screen is adjusted to different breakpoints.

Answer (score 5):

Vertical banner with slanted bottom

[image]

```
<div class="verticalbanner"></div>

.verticalbanner {
    background: #f8f8f8; //ribbon color
    height: 87px; // ribbon height
    width: 74px; // ribbon width
}
.verticalbanner:after,.verticalbanner:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-top: 15px solid #eee; // angle degree, reduce to reduce degree of angles
    height: 0; // no height, no content, just border
    width: 0;
    top: 100%;
}
.verticalbanner:after { // right angle
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    right:0;
}
.verticalbanner:before { // left angle
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    left:0;
}
```

[jsFiddle (link)](http://jsfiddle.net/davidcondrey/hrpc418m/)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of rotating a `div` to try and make the covered section, I would suggest using a `linear-gradient` to create the responsive triangle shape.

Im not sure if this is the direction of the 'end' you intended, but is what i assumed from the direction of the original `div` rotations.

So the left corner would look something like this

```
#ribbon .left_corner {
    width: 50%;
  bottom:0;
    left: 0;
  top:20px;
  position:absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(to right top,  #FFF 50%, transparent 50%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, right top, left bottom, color-stop(50%,transparent), color-stop(50%,#FFF));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right top,  #FFF 50%, transparent 50%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(to right top,  #FFF 50%, transparent 50%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(to right top,  #FFF 50%, transparent 50%);
  background: linear-gradient(to right top, #FFF 50%, transparent 50%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00ffffff', endColorstr='#ffffff',GradientType=1 );
}
```

Here is a formatted [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EzkoD). Note that this wont work on <=IE9.

PS. retabbed your HTML using [tabifier](http://tools.arantius.com/tabifier) and removed some dodgy CSS (you had some empty styles eg. `padding-left:;` which can cause issues)

Comment: Awesome, this seems to work great. I noticed that deepest level for Safari/webkit have been included, but it seems to get "blocky" in Safari testing. Any ideas? and thank you for Tabifier reference that will be a great resource from now on for me in the future.

Comment: seems to work fine for me on Safari, http://i.imgur.com/LeNnPS4.png . Can you provide a screenshot please.